# Display image in infowindow from URL Google Maps Android API

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a map in a fragment in a navigation drawer. Now the code for the map is found in the MainActivity.java of the navigation drawer. I have a for loop inside onMapReady which pin markers on my map. Now each iteration of the for loop takes retrieved data from Firebase, to be able to pin the markers. The retrieved data also contains URLs for images and I need to use those URLs to display an image in the infowindow of each marker. I've tried to understand the other solutions provided but I haven't got any idea how to implement this.

this is my code so far my code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    ...

    for (infoToStore details : info) {
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(details.getLat()), Double.parseDouble(details.getLng())))
        .title(details.getName())
        .snippet(details.getDesc()));

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've tried to implement it as follows but the infowindow is blank; not showing the TextViews nor the ImageView.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    for (final infoToStore details : info) {
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(details.getLat()), Double.parseDouble(details.getLng())))
        .title(details.getName())
        .snippet(details.getDesc()));

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

                TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);



                name.setText(marker.getTitle());
                desc.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(URLString)
                        .into(image);


                return v;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

here's the popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/desc"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create a Global Marker Variable

```
private Marker marker;
```

Now in your `onMapReady()` call

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
```

Create your `CustomInfoWindowAdapter` class and add the following code..

```
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View view;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup,null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        if (MainActivity.this.marker != null
                && MainActivity.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            MainActivity.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
            MainActivity.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
        MainActivity.this.marker = marker;

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(URLString)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // will be displayed if the image cannot be loaded
                .into(image);

        final String title = marker.getTitle();
        if (title != null) {
            name.setText(title);
        } else {
            name.setText("Default");
        }

        final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        if (snippet != null) {
            desc.setText(snippet);
        } else {
            desc.setText("Deafult");
        }
        //getInfoContents(marker);
        return view;
    }
}
```

your imageview is very large...which blocks the textView: try this layout in your popup

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sample Text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sample Text2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And for different image you need a arraylist of imageURL for different markers in the map.

Comment: I've tried it but the infowindow doesn't have any background and the image is not showing nor is the ic_launcher

Comment: what about the other textview's?

Comment: yeah the textviews are appearing though

Comment: did u add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in manifest?

Comment: there was a mistake in my code. it was not getting the URL for the image but now I fixed it. But the infowindow is still not working as it should. I edited the post to include a screenshot. And it's showing the same photo for both markers; both markers have different image URLs associated to them. And the TextViews are nowhere to be seen now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138525/discussion-between-jolan-goburdhun-and-rafsanahmad007).

Comment: Since the code is in a for loop, there is no need for an arraylist for the image URLs. I logged the URLs to check that each marker has it's own image URL and it is the case. But the problem is if I click on a particular marker for a first time, it will display the correct image, but if i continue to click on other markers, the same image remains. And how do I add a background to the infowindow? because there is no background right now.

Comment: you can set the background color in xml in infowindow...*for same image*...picasso has a caching technique..main thing is your `getInfoWindow()` method is called each time when selecting different marker. make sure different urlstrings are passed for different marker..and comment `//getInfoContents(marker);` this

Comment: in my for loop I did `URL = details.getUrl();` and `.load(URL)` for the Picasso. The Picasso is getting different URLs for different markers, right? because when I logged the URLs in the for loop, it showed me all the different URLs. As for the Picasso caching I tried to disable it but none of the markers would show any image. Hence, the problem of the same image showing for all the markers persists.